# How to put text on salesforce one app header?

Tags: salesforce

I have added a tab on to my salesforce one app.
On the tab I have some visual force pages .
I want to customize the header given by salesforce one to add text on to it.
KIndly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to put a header of salesforce one app.
   But the header color can be customized and further branding could be done.

```
1.From Setup, click Mobile Administration | Salesforce1 | Branding, then click Edit.
2.To customize brand color for key user interface elements, including the header, click Select a color or enter a valid hexadecimal color code.
3.To customize the background color of the loading page, click Select a color or enter a valid hexadecimal color code.
4.To customize the loading page logo, click Choose File to upload an image. Images can be .jpg, .gif, or .png files up to 200 KB in size. The maximum image size is 460 pixels by 560 pixels.
5.To customize the Salesforce1 Publisher icon image, click Choose File to upload an image. Images can be .jpg, .gif, or .png files up to 50 KB in size. The maximum image size is 88 pixels by 88 pixels.
6.Click Save.
```

[Reference Link](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_sf1_branding_edit.htm&language=en_US)